# Angular Firebase Register issue

Tags: angular

I am trying to save the data of my register user in firestore. And in user data i am saving the uID of user in firestore. But the problem is its saving the uid of user in firestore. But the docId is different. I need the doc id also same as user id.
Here is my code

```js
      signupUser(user: AppUser) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.firbaseAuth
            .auth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
            .then((signUpResponse) => {
              this.userType = user.usertype;
              localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
              signUpResponse.user.updateProfile({
                displayName: `${user.username}`
              }).then(() => {
                this.angularFirestore.collection('webUsers').add(user).then(ref => {
                  ref.set({ userID: this.firbaseAuth.auth.currentUser.uid }, { merge: true }).then(() => {
                  window.location.reload();
                  });
                })
                resolve();
              }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
              })
            }).catch((err) => {
              reject(err);
            });
        })
      }
```

Here is the image. The userId which is in data is same as in authentication userId. But dont know why the docid is not same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `add(user)` use `doc({id})`

```
this.angularFirestore.collection('webUsers').doc(this.firbaseAuth.auth.currentUser.uid ).then(ref => {
                  ref.set({...user ,userID: this.firbaseAuth.auth.currentUser.uid }).then(() => {
                  window.location.reload();
                  });
                })
```

Another improvement I would suggest use async/await to get rid of lot of `then`

```
const DocRef = await this.angularFirestore.collection('webUsers').doc(this.firbaseAuth.auth.currentUser.uid);
await ref.set({...user ,userID: this.firbaseAuth.auth.currentUser.uid });
window.location.reload();
```